# React Native: Image using prop as source leads to error

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am building a react native application and am trying to set the source of an image based on the contents that I am passing to the component as a prop. My code is as follows:

```
const nameOfComponent = props => {
    return (
        <View style={some style}>
            <Image source={require(props.imageURL)} style={some style} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

The prop imageURL is being passed down from the parent component by: 
`<nameOfComponent imageURL="../dir/name.png" />`

When including the code above in my project, I am met with an error saying "Invalid call at line 15: require(props.imageURL)".

Why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: did u verify the `require("../dir/name.png")`

Comment: Yes, it works correctly with a string value instead of props.imageURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to React-Native, all your image sources need to be loaded before compiling your bundle. So change your code as,

```
const nameOfComponent = props => (
    <View style={{ some_style }}>
        <Image source={props.imageURL} style={{ some_style }} />
    </View >
)
```

Call your child component as,

```
<nameOfComponent imageURL={require('imagepath')} />
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.